# Eclipse not being able to recognize special characters

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

My problem is when comparing a branch with the trunk (or vice-versa), using the option *Compare With* → *Branch/Tag* the Eclipse I'm using (Neon) points many special characters like ç, ã, õ ... as changed, but I really didn't changed anything there. This makes harder to see the real differences.

Is there an option to disable this check?

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an encoding or normalization mismatch.  The image appears to support the former hypothesis, but it's going to be difficult for us to evaluate the details remotely.

Comment: Try changing Preferences > General > Workspace - Text file encoding to UTF-8

Comment: Don't blindly follow Ivan's suggestion. You and your team should agree on text encoding. Could be UTF-8, could be Latin-1, could be CP-1252. But you all need to agree on it and use the same one. But we don't know what encoding is currently being used, so blindly switching to UTF-8 is premature.

Comment: Clearly encoding issue - it should be clear for you when you see some artifactis like question mark in square.

Comment: Ivan Pronin suggestion seems to have worked, the default text file encoding was Cp1252. I'll take dcsohl advice and talk to my team before applying this permanently. Thanks!